# TYPO3 ke_search custom indexer for accordions, cards etc. (all elements from bootstrap_package)?

Tags: search, typo3, indexer

Is there a simple way to write an indexer for all bootstrap_package elements (part of the introduction distribution) or do I have to write one for each element? I'd be happy for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't index each content element, but the whole page.

You index each record of a table, if those records have multiple kinds of display which are not included in one page each (like list view and detail view).

In general complex page elements like accordions, tabs or cards are rendered as plain text and some javascript (and CSS) rebuild the display to hide it partially. In this way the whole content can be indexed (but might be not visible directly if the page is called).

Comment: Meaning I don't have to write an indexer for the bootstrap elements? I have set up a page page indexer configuration. How can I include the bootstrap elements to list of content element types which should be indexed (default: text,textpic,bullets,table,html,header,uploads)

Comment: for all pages you do not only index the pure information from the `pages` record (like title, description, abstract, ...) but the generated HTML which includes all data from all the content elements in the page. That includes all 'plain' content elements. only complex CE like plugins which show special records in different views controlled by url-parameters you need additional work for indexing.

Comment: This might work with "indexed search" but not with "ke_search".

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ This will not work with ke_search extension, i already experienced this. ke_search is indexing "tt_content" tables but not the "tx_bootstrappackage_accordion_item" table, this is why any data for accordion or other bootstrap_package content elements will be missing in search results.